# ObjectListView - number of rows filtered

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, objectlistview

I have an `ObjectListView` populated with some data. I use a complicated `ModelFilter` to filter some rows out.

I would like to display a label above my `ObjectListView`:

```
Displaying 123 items out of 456.
```

Is there any way to find out how many rows passed the filter?

Comment: Can't you use a `DataGridView` bound to a `DataTable` instead?

Comment: @RezaAghaei No, I cannot, unfortunately. The project already exists for some time and it requires `ObjectListView`. This will be a new feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it is easy:

```
listView.Items.Count
```

is the number of rows displayed, not the number of all objects in `ObjectListView`.